# getting input from file in an android project

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a dictionary in android.
But i am facing problem to get input from text file.
I have put the text file in res/raw directory.
and write the code:

```
InputStream inputStream=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.Dictionary);
```

but <strike>having exception</strike> *my IDE indicates a problem* under raw word.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: What is the exception? Please add logcat and code

Comment: i have red underline under raw, saying raw cannot be resolved or not a field

Comment: In the packages, is com.packname.R included or android.R?

Comment: yes, will add object as raw in R file ? if it is added my text file is  then underlined

Comment: A red underline is not an Exception - an Exception is a run-time fault, but what you have is a build time problem.

Comment: You are not supposed to do anything to the R file. It is generated. I didn't get the answer to my previous question. Would you post the packages imported in your project here?

Comment: thanks Andy, my file started with capital letter i didn't notice it.my mistake...sorry

Answer (score -1):

Place the file in the assets folder and open it like this

getResources().getAssets().open("dictionary.txt");

Comment: This is just a less complete version of what is already in the question, and unrelated to the actual problem